# Youtube Data API V3 - Quota limit Varies Different on Different month?

Tags: youtube-data-api

I have a youtube data API v3 project setup with

> key: AIzaSyDZbBDtj8FPS-XbiI7frFXiylBpeBXXXXX

Currently daily quota limit is not displaying any value and still able to request and get data from Youtube Data Api v3. Since this is a development server key wherein on production server we were **previously having daily quota limit of 300 000 (On and before Jan2020)** but suddenly seeing the **only 250 000 without prior intimation**.

May I know what causes that limit getting decreasing/increasing in either of case.

Dashboard Limit

[image]

Comment: You should have removed the API key, sharing it is risky.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question for Google support

Answer (score 0):

If this is an issue with quota limit, you need to get in touch with google support, to resolve these issues.

Also if you have two apps of the same kind e.g. one is from desktop, the other is an iOS app, and they use different client IDs, you might have a problem. They would have disabled it.

If the app is of the same kind, its better to use a single client ID.

Comment: thats what they said on their community to avail support on stackoverflow for any queries

Comment: its a chicken and egg problem now. have you cross checked the start and end dates for the quota limit ? Somewhat similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39239982/youtube-api-quota-multiple-accounts?rq=1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56221425/youtube-data-api-maximum-queries-quota-per-day-decreased-to-0-and-cannot-set-any?rq=1